# Creating an array with a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, constant-expression

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   unsigned int endx = 5;
   unsigned int endy = 5;
   unsigned int endz = 5;

   int Matrix[endx+1][endy+1][endz+1] = {};

   return 0;
}
```

I get

> error C2057: expected constant expression

Ok, how can I create the Matrix like shown  in the code without vectors or dynamic allocated array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you need constant expressions to define array/matrix sizes; in that example, make integers `const` and it will compile.

```
const unsigned int endx = 5;
const unsigned int endy = 5;
const unsigned int endz = 5;
```

If you don't want dynamically allocated arrays or vectors, then you'll have to know the exact array size beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays require constants when creating them.  In this code, just making your end* variables `const unsigned int` should do it.

Comment: he do plus one: endx+1

Comment: Yes, if endx is type `const unsigned int` then `endx + 1` is still a constant.  It works...try it.